Variable number of generic parameters
I have a set of some parameters of different types. And I want to do some operation with them. But only if at least of one them is not null.
My code is something like this:
fun <A, B, C, R> atLeastOneNotNull(a: A?, b: B?, c: C?, block: (A?, B?, C?) -> R): R? {
    return if (atLeastOneNotNull(a, b) { _, _ -> } != null || c != null) {
        block(a, b, c)
    } else {
        null
    }
}

But the number of parameters varies in different use cases. In this example we have 3, but it could be 2 or 5.
Is it possible to create a function that would do the same but accept variable amount of parameters?
I have multiple functions for different number of paramaters, but i would like to have just one generic function.

Declaring them like that is the only option if you want to use typed arguments. If you don't need types you can use vararg args with lambda that consumes an array of args of single type.

If we need each parameter to be individually typed, as in your example, then I believe there is no better way than providing multiple functions.
This is actually a common pattern used in both Java and Kotlin world. For example, the combine function in Kotlin Flow API is duplicated for 2-5 parameters.
